# sidekiq update parameters before retrying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

How can I update an active job parameter before retrying? I have a job that needs some persistent storage so I store its data as an argument to the job (hash) and the data is updated after each job. If the job fails I want to retry with the updated data instead of the data that was used to schedule the job.

I am using sidekiq for scheduling my jobs btw.

Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to rescue and create a new job with the modified parameter.  Sidekiq does not allow you to modify a job from the Worker.

```
def perform(a)
  begin
    do_work
  rescue SomeError
    self.class.perform_async(a+1)
  end
end
```